# La Prise de Saint-Hélier - meaning of "je vous fiche dans la limonade"

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, paroles-de-chanson

There is a song "La Prise de Saint-Hélier" that contains the verse

> Bonsoir Monsieur le gouverneur
>   Je suis votre humble serviteur
>   Si vous bougez vous êtes malade
>   Et je vous fiche dans la limonade
>   Si vous ne cédez pas Saint-Hélier - Au père Regnier

For context, the song seems to be about a stealth attack on Saint-Hélier, and the attackers has just broken into the governor's residence. My attempt at a translation of this verse is below.

> Good Evening, Mister Governor
>   I am your humble servant (sarcasm)
>   If you move then you are ill (perhaps "don't move, or else")
>   And I will plug you in the lemonade
>   If you do not hand over/give up Saint Helier - To father Regnier

"I will plug you in the lemonade" doesn't seem to make any sense at all. I'm fairly sure it's a threat of some kind, given the rest of the song. I wondered if it meant "I will throw you in the drink", meaning "I will throw you in the harbour" (see http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+in+the+drink), but phrased strangely to rhyme with malade. Then, I thought that I was making too many assumptions about shared idioms.

**So what does "je vous fiche dans la limonade" mean?**

Comment: If anyone is interested in hearing the song, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCBwrEFvHp0 has a recording of it. I don't like this one as much as the one I first heard, performed by a group called Strand Hugg, but I couldn't find a recording of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a variation on the 19th century slang expressions “*être dans la limonade*” or “*tomber dans la limonade*”, in which *limonade* means a difficult situation (pretty much like “in a pickle” in English). I don't think I've ever heard this, it seems out of fashion. The [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/limonade) gives a 1880 citation. The synonym “*être dans la [panade](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/panade)*” is more common today.

I don't know what the etymology of this expression is. It may be loosely related to the use of [*limonade*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ZkGdBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=%22%C3%AAtre+dans+la+limonade%22) to mean something cheap, worthless (also outmoded slang).

The use of *limonade* here could be a pun inasmuch as it could also be a metaphor for water (i.e. the sea — Saint-Hélier is on an island).

Comment: Thanks! This has been confusing me for (literally) years, and I couldn't find an answer anywhere. I'll give you the +1 when I have the needed rep. :)

Comment: « Être dans la panade » a d'abord voulu dire « être dans la misère », ce n'est que par extension que le terme *panade* en est venu à signifier *embarras*, pas seulement financier. Mais de toutes façons ici ce n'est clairement pas le sens du mot *limonade* qui veut bien dire *eau*.

Answer (score 5):

Le registre de cette chanson de marin est familier, et il faut comprendre *limonade* dans son sens argotique d'**eau**.
« Je vous fiche dans la limonade » veut donc bien dire « je vous jette à l'eau » comme tu l'as supposé. Et le mot « limonade » a été préféré à « eau » pour la rime avec « malade » (qu'il faut ici comprendre par « mal en point », voire « mort »).

*La prise de Saint-Hélier* est une chanson de marin qui relate la prise de Saint-Hélier en 1781 lors de la [bataille de Jersey](http://aufildesmotsetdelhistoire.unblog.fr/2014/01/19/le-6-janvier-1781-la-bataille-de-jersey/) par les français sous le commandement du baron de Rullecourt ([engagé par le  capitaine Régnier pour prendre Jersey](https://archive.org/stream/legouvernementde02hipp/legouvernementde02hipp_djvu.txt)).

*Limonade* a aussi pris au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle le sens argotique de *misère*, *dèche*. Il vient s'ajouter aux expressions populaires imagées déjà existantes pour désigner la misère et liées à la nourriture : [mouise](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mouise), [purée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pur%C3%A9e), [panade](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/panade), plats des classes populaires.
*Le dictionnaire du français  non conventionnel* (Jacques Cellard et Alain Rey) nous dit que *limonade* a été choisi à cause de la proximité phonétique avec *panade*. Et précise que « la limonade n'a pas la consistance misérable de la *purée* ou de la *mouise* ». C'est à dire qu'il est plus facile de se sortir de la limonade plus liquide que la purée ou la mouise.

« Être dans la panade » a d'abord voulu dire être dans la misère, et c'est par extension que maintenant l'expression a pris le sens plus général d'être dans l'embarras, pas seulement financier.

---

*Limonade*  is a now obsolete slang word for *water*, and that's what it means here.
*La prise de Saint-Hélier* is a sailor's song that relates the attack on Saint-Hélier in 1781 by Baron de Rullecourt who had been hired by Capitaine Régnier for that purpose. The Governor in the song is  Major Moses Corbet who was forced to capitulate on the morning of January 6th, 1781.

The word *limonade* can also be used as slang for extreme poverty.  Coined after the word *panade*, both pertaining to the semantic field of food.

An account in English of the battle of Jersey [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Jersey).

Comment: Au départ la panade est la soupe du pauvre : du pain sec que l'on met au fond de l'assiette et que l'on réchauffe avec un peu d'eau. C'est la soupe du pauvre que l'on enrichit de légumes, parfois de lardons ou d'œufs chez les gens plus aisés et que la bourgeoisie va transformer en potage, consommé beaucoup plus richement dotés. D'où l'expression "Tu seras au pain sec et à l'eau fraîche" (même pas une soupe chaude) pour prévenir quelqu'un les privations de nourritures qu'on va lui infliger pour le punir. Être marin et être à la limonade et non au vin, est une privation réelle.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, *fiche* here does not mean the verb *ficher*, but rather is a common minced version of the obscene verb *foutre*, which has a wider range of syntactic uses than the English *fuck*. In this particular case, the literal meaning is something along the lines of "put", "throw" or shove".